# Access and update shell script variable in other script

Tags: shell

I have a shell script *parent.sh* like this. I want the variable *flag* to be used in the *child.sh*, update the value of *flag* there and get the updated value back in *parent.sh*. How can I achieve this.

```
#!/bin/bash
flag=999       #I want ths flag in child.sh and there i will update its value depending on some condition
$HOME/child.sh
if [ $? -eq $flag ];then   #The value of flag got changed on child.sh
echo "Success"
else
echo "Failed"
fi
```

And my *child.sh* is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
hive -f $HOME/creat.hql          #It should be create.hql so it will fail.
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
    flag=0
else
    flag=1     #This will execute and I want this change to be get reflected in parent.sh
fi
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use both the return value of the child.sh as well as the changed flag variable? You could simply put `exit $flag` at the end of child.sh and then use `if [ $flag -eq 0 ]; then echo "Success" `...

Comment: how i can access variable _flag_ in _child.sh_

Comment: Use `flag=$?` directly after the call so that you have the return value (that you set with `exit $flag` in the script). You don't use the flag value from the script but you have the same value (assuming that the values can only be 0-127). I meant to say `if  [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ... echo "Success"` in my above comment but it is safer to assign the exit value to a variable, and if you wish that can of course also be called `flag`

Comment: @StefanHegny I got the idea from your comments. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

You need to `source` `child.sh` in your `parent.sh` so that it's executed in *current* subshell:

```
#!/bin/bash
flag=999       #I want ths flag in child.sh and there i will update its value depending on some condition
. ./child.sh
if [ $? -eq $flag ];then   #The value of flag got changed on child.sh
echo "Success"
else
echo "Failed"
fi
```

You can check vaule of `flag` right after sourcing `child.sh` to make sure that it was correctly set inside `child.sh`. See `help source` or `help .` inside `bash` for more info on how `source` works.

Comment: _source_ makes all the commands in _child.sh_ to execute which i do not want. I only want to access and use the _flag_ variable

Comment: I don't think you can do it. Every script is executed in a separate bash process and there is no way for a child to modify environment of its parent.